# touch effect for Button in iphone

Tags: iphone

how can i just change the color,of a button when i set the focus on the button in iphone.
I mean to say , for example we have 5 buttons, and i am just setting the focus on each of the button. i want those buttons to be higlighted  with different color.
 but when  press or touch up inside the utton, the navigation is made to the respective forms, that is set for that button.

Comment: so if i understand you right, you want the button to be highlighted as you "focus" on it not unlike in windows with form item focusing?

Comment: i did not get you....but just lets say in the stackoverflow site itself.
on the top i have 5 buttons, Questions, Tags,Users, badges,Unanswered.
Now when we focus anyone of them , the color changes to yellow.
I want something like this in iphone

Answer (score 0):

you can write method, for example, let it be

> ```
> - (void) changeButtonState:(UIButton*) buttonToChange;
> ```

then you can call it in your onBtnClk method for button you need. in that method you can change image for your button's UIControlStateNormal mode. and if I understand right, you can use toolbar or tabbar instead of buttons.

Comment: you mean to say when i will have to click the button , and then on button click event call this function.But in button click event i am navigating to other form.I just want to change color, when i just keep focus on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have already asked this issue differently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747902/highlight-the-buttons-when-the-focus-is-on-it)..

But have you checked the answer?? You can use any of those methods at your will!

Comment: Please can you help me with the code for just say setTitleColor method.
and the steps to do it..